# Resolving ambiguity of the grammar

Tags: programming-languages, grammar, ambiguous-grammar

I have a grammar rules like that;

```
S -> S and S
S -> S or S
S -> (S)
S -> true | false

-- and , or , ( , ) , true ,false are terminals --
```

I can find out that this grammar is ambiguous, but how can I modify this grammar to solve the ambiguity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach is to give them precedence/associativity:

```
S -> S or  A | A
A -> A and P | P
P -> (S)
P -> true | false
```

Comment: Thank you so much , I got it now.